# Remove left border of Tikz Node text / Write text directly at left edge of node

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I am trying to get rid of the whitespace on the left side of my TIKZ picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0)  {Date and signature:};
\draw(1.7,-0.19)--(9.7,-0.19);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to crop the whitespace?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner sep=0

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0] at (0,0)  {Date and signature:};
\draw(1.7,-0.19)--(9.7,-0.19);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: See also `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`.